# How do I make a HTML button open in random links in new tab

Tags: html, button, tabs

So I am creating a uselesswebsite and I need to make a button that directs people to random websites in new tabs. I already have the random link button code but I cant seem to add it with the new tab code.

sample

```
var randomlinks=new Array(10)

 randomlinks[0]="http://ducksarethebest.com/"
 randomlinks[1]="http://cant-not-tweet-this.com/"
 randomlinks[2]="http://just-shower-thoughts.tumblr.com/"
 randomlinks[3]="http://www.fallingfalling.com/"
 randomlinks[4]="http://www.partridgegetslucky.com/"
 randomlinks[5]="http://ducksarethebest.com/"
 randomlinks[6]="http://cant-not-tweet-this.com/"
 randomlinks[7]="http://just-shower-thoughts.tumblr.com/"
 randomlinks[8]="http://www.fallingfalling.com/"
 randomlinks[9]="http://www.staggeringbeauty.com/"
 randomlinks[10]="http://www.trypap.com/"

function randomlink(){
window.location=randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]
}
```

Html

```
    <form method="post">
    <p><input type="button" name="B1" value="Random Link >>" onclick="randomlink()""window.open'"></p> 
</form>
    or
    <a href="javascript:randomlink()">Random Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `window.open(url)` instead of `window.location(url)`.

`window.location(url)` means: setting the url of the current tab.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Example: (doesn't work on stackoverflow cause sandboxed frame)

```js
var randomlinks = [];
randomlinks[0]="http://ducksarethebest.com/";
randomlinks[1]="http://cant-not-tweet-this.com/";
randomlinks[2]="http://just-shower-thoughts.tumblr.com/";
randomlinks[3]="http://www.fallingfalling.com/";
randomlinks[4]="http://www.partridgegetslucky.com/";
randomlinks[5]="http://ducksarethebest.com/";
randomlinks[6]="http://cant-not-tweet-this.com/";
randomlinks[7]="http://just-shower-thoughts.tumblr.com/";
randomlinks[8]="http://www.fallingfalling.com/";
randomlinks[9]="http://www.staggeringbeauty.com/";
randomlinks[10]="http://www.trypap.com/";

function randomlink(){
  window.open(randomlinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length)]);
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <p><input type="button" name="B1" value="Random Link >>" onclick="randomlink()"></p> 
</form>
    or
<a href="#" onclick="randomlink()">Random Link</a>
```

Comment: So can you tell me the full code i should use and add.