# Var returning 'undefined' ASP.net mvc

Tags: javascript

I didn't want to use the default site.js, but just write the Javascript on the view page itself, "its kinda confusing for me". but still, after further exploration online, I still cannot figure out why I am not redirected as intended. I tried running codes from https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/414946-pick-website-from-random-list-redirect/
and [How do I make a HTML button open in random links in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956901/how-do-i-make-a-html-button-open-in-random-links-in-new-tab)
in which both seemed to work in online simulator, w3school. But when I replicated the functions, it seemed to return a null/undefined value for redirection.

Code:

```
var Links = ['https://longdogechallenge.com/ ',
    'http://heeeeeeeey.com/ ',
    'http://corndog.io/ ',
    'https://thezen.zone/ ',
    'http://hasthelargehadroncolliderdestroyedtheworldyet.com/ ',
    // lots more snipped
    'http://papertoilet.com/ '];


var RandFx = Links[Math.floor(Math.random * Links.length)];

function RandX() {
    window.location = RandFx;
}
```

As stated, the `RandFx` seems to be containing undefined value. What am I doing incorrectly? can it be due to the extended length of urls in the `Links` variable?

Comment: `Math.random` is a function, you should be using `Math.random()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.random` is a function, you should be using `Math.random()` to get the actual result:

```
var RandFx = Links[Math.floor(Math.random() * Links.length)];
```

Comment: oh so when im writing anything apart from c#, the auto corrector doesn't like correct me or halt the build process due to script error?

Comment: Even the C# IDE wouldn't correct that kind of thing for you since it's a useful thing to do in some circumstances (if you want to pass the function around instead of the functions result). Also Javascript is very loosely typed so will often let you do almost anything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the index you are calculating results in NaN:

```
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random * Links.length)
  var RandFx = Links[index];
```

And `Links[NaN]` is undefined.

The index is `NaN` because you are calling `Math.random` instead of `Math.random()`. Passing the function instead of the result of the function gives you an error.

This jsfiddle shows what's happening: https://jsfiddle.net/74skonhL/